# Write special UTF8 characters in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf, utf-8, migradoc

I want to write the "█"-character in a MigraDoc pdf file.
The following code doesn't show the character. Here is a small part of my code.

```
PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(false, embedding);
row.Cells[1].AddParagraph().AddFormattedText("aaaaa \u2588", new Font("Arial Unicode MS"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to pass `true` to the c'tor of `PdfDocumentRenderer` to activate Unicode for rendering.

A small part of my code:

```
// Create a renderer for the MigraDoc document.
var pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true) { Document = doc };
```

More code here:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx