# Display Unicode characters in PDF using MigraDoc DocumentRenderer

Tags: c#, pdf, unicode, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm trying to use Unicode characters in my PDF generator. I first create main layout for pages with PDFsharp (like watermarks and shapes on every page) and then try to add text with MigraDoc. While in PDFsharp everything goes well with fonts and the code works fine, MigraDoc creates empty characters. The simplyfied code looks like so:

```
//with PDFsharp
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
string s = "ĄŻŹĆĘŁÓążźęćłó";
XFont font16 = new XFont("Calibri", 16, XFontStyle.Regular);
gfx.DrawString(s, font16, XBrushes.Black, 70, 50, XStringFormats.Default);

//with MigraDoc
Document doc = new Document();
Section sec = doc.AddSection();
Paragraph para = sec.AddParagraph();
para.Format.Font.Name = "Calibri";
para.Format.Font.Size = 16;
para.AddText(s);

MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
docRenderer.PrepareDocument();
docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, 1);
//

document.Save("test.pdf");
Process.Start("test.pdf");
```

I tried different fonts and it gave me nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `gfx.MUH = PdfFontEncoding.Unicode;` for the `gfx` before invoking any MigraDoc code.

A note for beginners reading here: Life is simpler if you use `PdfDocumentRenderer`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192026/162529
You can use images or PDF pages as page backgrounds using MigraDoc features only without having to mix MigraDoc and PDFsharp.

`DocumentRenderer` allows to mix PDFsharp and MigraDoc - to achieve functionality that goes beyond the capabilities of MigraDoc alone. In this case you have to use the MigraDoc Unicode Hack MUH shown above to enable Unicode support. The MUH is also used in the official mixing sample on the PDFsharp site:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx
It is also used in this sample published on the PDFsharp forum:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3172

Comment: Thank you, the setting works great. 
Does the PdfDocumentRenderer give you the possibility to create images and shapes beneeth the text as PDFsharp does?

Comment: @user2638817 Images are Shapes. You can use Shapes out of the normal text flow at absolute positions. You can add Shapes e.g. to the page header - this could be a PDF page with company header and footer that is used to fill the whole page as a background. I updated my post. `PdfDocumentRenderer` may give you the functionality you need, but `DocumentRenderer` may lead to "cleaner" code by creating the page background with PDFsharp while creating the contents with MigraDoc. In many cases both ways will work and then it is a matter of taste.